Use css next sibling selector (+) with css scope rule
Trying to figure out why this works:


const aa = document.querySelector('div');
//const bb = aa.querySelector(':scope + aside');
const bb = aa.querySelector(':scope > aside');

console.log(bb.classList[0]);
<div>Div<aside class="zoe yip xin"> span</aside></div>
<aside class="abe bob cam">Aside</aside>



but this does not:


const aa = document.querySelector('div');
const bb = aa.querySelector(':scope + aside');
//const bb = aa.querySelector(':scope > aside');

console.log(bb.classList[0]);
<div>Div<aside class="zoe yip xin"> span</aside></div>
<aside class="abe bob cam">Aside</aside>



The first example uses :scope > aside to grab the nested aside,while the second uses :scope + aside to TRY / FAIL to grab the sibling aside
The desired result is to use the aa selector to cache the sibling aside.abe.bob.cam element.

When you start the selector with ":scope", you're limiting the DOM to the descendants of the starting point. That sibling <aside> is not a descendant.

I believe it's because the sibling aside is not in the nested :scope of the first div (since it's not in its subtree). Your best option would be to target it using div + aside

As blurfus and Pointy pointyd out, the :scope css rule is limited to the descendants of the starting element.
The correct solution in this instance was to use the .nextElementSibling property, as documented in Barmar's answer to this other question
=-=-=-=-=-
Actually, it later ocurred to me that I could have used parentNode with the + selector in a simpler way that I was imagining (still taking advantage of the easily found element, with the next sibling (+) selector) :


const aa = document.querySelector('div');
const bb = aa.parentNode.querySelector('div + aside');

console.log(bb.classList[0]);
<section>
  <div>Div<aside class="zoe yip xin"> span</aside></div>
  <aside class="abe bob cam">Aside</aside>
</section>



However, Barmar reminded me of the .nextElementSibling property, which was definitely the correct tool for this task.
